# How to multiply a number to every elements expressed by scientific notation in my list?

Tags: python

I have a data.txt as:

```
1.30000E+01 7.49106E+01

1.40000E+01 7.24673E+01
```

...

I want to multiply the first column by 2. Here are my codes:

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
data = f.readlines()

xtemp = [row.split()[0] for row in data]
y = [row.split()[1] for row in data]
x = [i * 2 for i in xtemp]
```

the error information is

`eError: invalid literal for float():1.30000E+011.30000E+01`

Comment: At least one of your input lines doesn't have a space separating the numbers.

Comment: @user2357112 That is incorrect. It is printing the trying twice because when you multiply a string by two it concatenates it to itself.

Comment: please properly indent your code after `with`

Comment: @SamCraig: On second thought, yeah, this code doesn't show the `float` call. It seems to be happening after the `* 2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data read from a file is of type string. You need to convert to float to multiply:

```
x = [float(i) * 2 for i in xtemp]
```

---

```
import io

filedata = """1.30000E+01 7.49106E+01
1.40000E+01 7.24673E+01"""

data = [i.strip("\n") for i in io.StringIO(filedata).readlines()]

xtemp = [row.split()[0] for row in data]
y = [row.split()[1] for row in data]
xtype = [type(i) for i in xtemp] # [str,str] <-- here is your problem
x = [float(i) * 2 for i in xtemp]


x
```

Returns

```
[26.0, 28.0]
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: @H.Y.Long I'm just glad I could help!